# HTML tag textfield in java

Tags: java

I am currently working on implementing a chat server and client as part of an introductory course I don't have any problems on the server side , however on the client side specifically the GUI I am a bit lost , what I want to do is some sort of text field that will server two purposes :

1)the chat history , messages sent and received and should allow some tagging for example 
a message appears user1 : bla bla  , and the user clicks on the user name I would like that to trigger an event allowing for example to add to friends list or ignore and that sort
I would also like it to be formatted as in text colors , font size and type.

2) the area where the user enters text or commands I would like to also add some buttons to be able to format that same as above without the event part

My first thought on the matter was using HTML tags and JEditorPane for both but I am not sure how I would be able to register an event to clicking a user name also
and I am not sure if it will  have to be a complete HTML document for it to be displayed on an EditorPane with the HTML kit ? will simply

```
Text message <b> this part bold </b>
```

display without problems ?

Also I would like to point out that I am not looking for code as I am only in the planning phase of the client application , I am looking for someone to point me in the right direction in the Swing API  , that is not overly complicated to implement and can provide such features

I will be glad to elaborate more if the question was not clear

~Thanks

Comment: Generally when you wish a swing component to display text formatted with HTML you'll want to enclose it within `<html></html>`. `JEditorPane` is intended to render HTML specifically and as such supports hyperlinks so your buttons might aswell be ones. All you need to do is implement a `HyperlinkListener` and attach it to said component. This enables you to obtain the URL of a clicked hyperlink. See [here](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JEditorPane.html)